# Should I use 'in' or 'or' in an if statement in Python 3.x to check a variable against multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, if-statement

Suppose I have the following, which is the better, faster, more Pythonic method
and why?

```
if x == 2 or x == 3 or x == 4:
    do following...
```

or :

```
if x in (2, 3, 4):
    do following...
```

Comment: as for the pythonic aspect, the 2nd version would be more suited. (taken from : http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html). I don't know about performance though, but I believe it should be equivalent

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Python 3 (3.2 and up), you should use a *set*:

```
if x in {2, 3, 4}:
```

as set membership is a O(1) test, versus a worst-case performance of O(N) for testing with separate `or` equality tests or using membership in a tuple.

In Python 3, the set literal will be optimised to use a `frozenset` constant:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('x in {1, 2, 3}', '<file>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 (frozenset({1, 2, 3}))
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 POP_TOP
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that this optimisation was [added to Python 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations) and in Python 2 or 3.0 or 3.1 you'd be better of using a tuple instead. For a small number of elements, the difference in lookup time is nullified by the set creation for each execution.

Comment: I never thought of using a set for this, just kept the old habit of using tuples, but when I read it here I thought "well, of course!". So thanks!

Comment: If set membership is an O(1) test, I assume that the values in a set are hashed?

Comment: @JacobodeVera: Older Python versions (Python 2.x, Python 3.0 and 3.1) don't support the optimisation yet, and construct a new set object every time a `x in {.., .., ..}` line is executed.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense: they are, just like dictionary keys.